# Copy Data from Workbooks Sheet1 to Master Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have macro, which copies data from selected workbooks' Sheet1 to this main workbook's Sheet1 in last row. For small number of files, it is fast, but when I select more files (say 20), it breaks and excel even crashes. How to make this more efficient as I am already using Application.EnableEvents and ScreenUpdating?

```
Sub Copy_From_Workbooks()

    Dim numberOfFilesChosen, i As Integer
    Dim tempFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim loLastRow As Long

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set tempFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    tempFileDialog.Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsx?", 1
    tempFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = True
    numberOfFilesChosen = tempFileDialog.Show

    For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count
        Workbooks.Open tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i)
        Set sourceWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
        If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") <> "" Then
            With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
                With .Cells(1).CurrentRegion
                    .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1).Copy
                End With
            End With
        End If
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
            loLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("A" & loLastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            'ThisWorkbook.Save
        End With
        sourceWorkbook.Close
    Next i
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually your code looks ok. I just would combine `Workbooks.Open` with `Set sourceWorkbook` to `Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i))` and stay away from all `ActiveWorkbook` statements use `sourceWorkbook` instead. This makes it more reliable. • I can think of 2 possible issues: ① It could be that if you open an close a workbook that Excel doesn't properly free all memory used by that workbook. If you do it a lot your Excel crashes because it runs out of memory. ② You have a corrupt worbook that crashes Excel.

Comment: Test if it always crashes after the same amount of files, or if it carshes on one specific file (no matter which count this file is). Maybe you can narrow down to the issue this way. • Test if making `Workbooks.Open` read only has any positive effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You set a variable for the source workbook, but do not use it.
2. Use `With blocks` so you don't call the referencing object over and over and over.
3. Write the values directly as opposed to using the slower copy/paste.

   ```
   For i = 1 To tempFileDialog.SelectedItems.Count
       Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(tempFileDialog.SelectedItems(i))
       With sourceWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
           If .Range("A1") <> "" Then
               Dim valRange as Range
               With .Cells(1).CurrentRegion
                   Set valRange = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1)
               End With
           End With
       End If

       With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
           loLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
           .Range("A" & loLastRow).Resize(valRange.Rows.Count,valRange.Columns.Count).Value = valRange.Value
           'ThisWorkbook.Save
       End With
       sourceWorkbook.Close
   Next i
   ```

Comment: @peh - thanks for edit. i was in the process of doing it myself but was having a helluva time getting it straight for some reason.

Comment: I think your answer explains why it could be slow, but It doesn't explain why Excel would crash. But anyway I have no solution, guess it is a memory issue or something like that.

Comment: @peh - but with the optimized code Excel is like likely to crash, so in the end, perhaps that stops the crashing. If it's still crashing, then I agree with your comments that it could be file specific.

Comment: I agree. OP's turn.

Comment: Thanks ScottHoltzman @PEH It is now working fine, and did not freeze. Regarding memory, I closed all other workbooks, folders and windows to confirm whether it was a memory issue or not. Cheers :)

Comment: @StarShines - glad it works. see my edit, I accidentally left one `ActiveWorkbook` in the `With block`, instead of `sourceWorkbook`. Also, really learning these principles will help your coding experience tremendously moving forward.